# Cannot convert non-nullable type conversion problems vb.net to c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, enums, non-nullable

I have copied a piece of legacy code written in VB.Net which when converted to C# has produced the following:

```
///<summary>
    ///Test whether SSAC should be serialized
    ///</summary>
    public virtual bool ShouldSerializeSSAC()
    {
        if (_shouldSerializeSSAC)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return (_sSAC != (SSAC_Type)null);
    }
```

It is throwing an error stating it cannot convert because  it is a non-nullable type. The code for the SSAC is as follows:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.6.81.0"), System.SerializableAttribute()]
public enum SSAC_Type
{

    ///<remarks/>
    A,

    ///<remarks/>
    B,

    ///<remarks/>
    C,

    ///<remarks/>
    D,

    ///<remarks/>
    E,

    ///<remarks/>
    F,

    ///<remarks/>
    G,

    ///<remarks/>
    H,

    ///<remarks/>
    J
}
```

In VB.Net this function was as follows:

```
Public Overridable Function ShouldSerializeSSAC() As Boolean
        If _shouldSerializeSSAC Then
            Return True
        End If
        Return (_sSAC <> CType(Nothing, SSAC_Type))
    End Function
```

While the SSAC class was as follows:

```
 <System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.6.81.0"),
 System.SerializableAttribute()>
Public Enum SSAC_Type

    '''<remarks/>
    A

    '''<remarks/>
    B

    '''<remarks/>
    C

    '''<remarks/>
    D

    '''<remarks/>
    E

    '''<remarks/>
    F

    '''<remarks/>
    G

    '''<remarks/>
    H

    '''<remarks/>
    J
End Enum
```

How can I update the C# code to fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, "fix" may not be the best term to use here, since it was probably unintended behavior in the VB code. But, if by "fix", you mean, how do you make it work the same, then the answer is that the C# code should return `(_sSAC != SSAC_Type.A)`. To actually correct it, `_sSAC` should be declared as `SSAC_Type?` (nullable), then you could just return `_sSAC.HasValue`. The reason it worked in VB is because `Nothing` in VB is not exactly equivalent to `null` in C#. `Nothing` actually means the *default* value for any given type, so for an integer, like an enum, the default is 0.

Comment: Does this mean that the return (_sSAC != (SSAC_Type)null); always returns the first object in the enum list?

Comment: No. It returns a Boolean. It returns true if _ssac doesn't equal A (0).

Comment: OK I see where I can set the SSAC_Type? as nullable, what do you mean in relation to returning the _sSAC.HasValue? I cannot see a HasValue method only a HasFlag

Comment: I'm just guessing that that was what the code was unsuccessfully intending to do.

Comment: I think the issue you need to decide is what the VB was _trying_ to do and what you want it to so.  It's pretty much nonsense as it was written.  So you need to decide if it should check against the value zero, or rewrite the whole thing so that _sSac is Nullable.  It's not so much a question of translation as deciding what you need and writing accordingly.

Comment: @StuartWhitehouse Thanks for explaining that better than I did. I was driving so I couldn't respond more thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

'Nothing' when applied to an enum instance is always '0' in VB, whether or not the first value of the enum is explicitly set to anything else. That is, the actual first value of the enum is irrelevant.
So the C# equivalent to your method is:

```
public virtual bool ShouldSerializeSSAC()
{
    if (_shouldSerializeSSAC)
        return true;

    return (_sSAC != 0);
}
```

Comment: thanks Dave ive opted for the changing of the variables to be nullables and returning _sSAC.HasValue